# What is japanese?

Tags: learning, academic-japanese, old-japanese

I'm mostly a self-learner, i have never learned anything from taking courses or educational institutions. But instead, i have always managed to figure out "how to learn things" by either asking or researching and then i do the rest on my own.

From what i have read so far about learning japanese, i figured it would be a bad idea to waste time learning things too early or too late or even learn things that i don't understand quite right.

So, my actual question is,

What exactly is japanese? Was it originated from another language? What does it consist of, entirely?

What is kana? I know it is a modern thing which means that you can learn the language without it, right! So why should i do learn it? What are other forms like it? And what are they used for?

Comment: 1) It's a language. 2) No, it's an isolate. 3) Words. 4) Two syllabaries for writing Japanese. 5) If you consider the 9th century modern, sure. 6) Because it's part of the language. 7) I have no idea what you are asking here. 8) Everything that is not kanji. 9) You really should find a course to enrol to.

Comment: **You cannot learn the language without kana.** Kana is a main part of the Japanese writing system. You can, perhaps, *listen* and *speak* Japanese without them, but you definitely **cannot read or write** Japanese without knowing Kana. Also, although kana is not directly used in listening and speaking, knowing it will actually make it easier for you to master it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reading the introduction of Tae Kim' Guide to Japanese.:
http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/introduction